# When to use framework in Objective C development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Not many libraries such as GHUnit suggest you to use them as a Framework.

While most libraries such as Facebook iOS SDK just require you to drag the project into existing XCode project.

So when you are building a library which suppose to be re-use by other project in the future, should you use Framework or just like many current opensource projects, don't use Framework provided by XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason why those opensource projects are provided as static libraries or just source code and not Framework, Frameworks are currently not supported by iOS SDK.

You can only use Frameworks provided by Apple - parts of SDK itself. Your code cannot be linked against your own or third party Frameworks.

So stick with one of those ways - I personally prefer static libraries.